# Using function argument inside grepl pattern (R)

Tags: r, grepl

Is there a way to use an argument from a user-defined function as part of grepl pattern?

Ex:

```
Function1 <- function(x, y) {
    grepl(pattern = ".*\\sy", x)
}
```

whereby the "y" inside the pattern would differ according to how you called the function,

ie:

```
data <- c("Joe Smith", "John Doe")
Function1(data, S)
```

would return

```
[1] TRUE FALSE
```

Is there a way for `grepl` to recognize `y` as an outside variable? (I've tried `'y'` `\\y` and `y` inside backticks to no effect)

Comment: `grepl(sprintf(".*\\s%s", y), x)` could be used as well.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern is just a string. you can use `paste()` for string concatenation

```
grepl(pattern = paste(".*\\s",y), x)
```

There is no other "special" way to reference variables inside the regular expression string.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your pattern by using `paste0()`:

```
Function1 <- function(x,y) {
            grepl(pattern = paste0(".*\\s",y), x)
            }
Function1(data, 'S')
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: I would guess that you are posting the same answer as the other post

Comment: That is also true. Plus one.

Comment: @HubertL This does work, thank you. However, why does `paste0()` work and `paste()` does not?

Comment: aha after some thought I believe it has to do with the default `sep=""` of `paste0()`